# On execution of batch process unique constraint violated error

Tags: oracle

On running of particular batch data from one table of local server have to move to the another table of host server. data is present in local server but the same data is not moving to another table. and there is an error like unique constraint (index_id) violated. please suggest what might be the exact reason for this?

Comment: exactly what the error says.  The table you are inserting into has a unique constraint on one or more columns, and the data you are trying to insert has has values that already exists on those columns.

Comment: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ALERTUSER.IDX_ASBT) violated this is the exact error

Answer (score 1):

The destination table (`ALERTUSER`) has a unique constraint (`IDX_ASBT`). Your attempt to enter the data from your source table would cause this constraint to be violated, hence the error.

It could be that both tables have a row with matching values in the columns specified in the constraint. Alternately, if the columns in question are *not* unique in the source table, then it may be that none of the existing data in the destination table matches the same data in the source table, but that the source table has multiple rows with the same data, something the destination table doesn't allow.

You'll need to determine how this should be handled; the specifics will depend on the data in question, and the specifics of how your DB is used.

Some options include:

- Where the source table matches the destination table, either update the destination table with the data from the source table, or discard the source table rows.
- Where the source table has duplicate rows, determine how those rows should be combined to form one row in the destination table. You may need to aggregate some columns, or you may just want to copy over the most recent row.
- As a last resort, you could remove the unique constraint. I would only do this if you determine that the unique constraint is no longer valid for the destination table. you risk breaking applications that use the destination table, as they may rely on the uniqueness of those columns in some way. There's no point in temporarily removing the constraint - fix the data before completing the data move.